# ocl-facedetect sample of opencv 2.4.6.1

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, ubuntu-12.04, ocl

![enter image description here][1]On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with NVidia GeForce 8 series GPU card, I am trying to run the ocl-facedetect sample of OpenCV 2.4.6.1 and seeing following error:

$./ocl-example-facedetect -t haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml -i friends.jpg 
In image read
loop0
~~~~ Loading convertC3C4
Building source:./convertC3C4_GeForce 8600 GT -D GENTYPE4=uchar4.clb
~~~~ Loading RGB2Gray
Building source:./RGB2Gray_GeForce 8600 GT -D DEPTH_0.clb
~~~~ Loading resizeLN_C1_D0
Building source:./resizeLN_C1_D0_GeForce 8600 GT .clb
~~~~ Loading set_to_without_mask
Building source:./set_to_without_mask_GeForce 8600 GT -D GENTYPE=int.clb
~~~~ Loading calc_sub_hist_D0
Building source:./calc_sub_hist_D0_GeForce 8600 GT .clb
clCreateProgramWithSource status=0

clBuildProgram status=-11

BUILD LOG (0) Error: unsupported operation OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) in openCLGetKernelFromSource, file /home/ovuser/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/ocl/src/initialization.cpp, line 664 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what(): /home/ovuser/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/ocl/src/initialization.cpp:664: error: (-217) CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE in function openCLGetKernelFromSource

It seems the OpenCL compiler is unable to build calc_sub_hist_D0 kernel required by the face detect sample. I have put some verbose messages and attached kernel source causing the problem. Can someone point out what's wrong with the kernel source?

```
enter code here

#define PARTIAL_HISTOGRAM256_COUNT     (256)
#define HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT         (256)
#define HISTOGRAM256_WORK_GROUP_SIZE     (256)
#define HISTOGRAM256_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE      (HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT)
#define NBANKS (16)
#define NBANKS_BIT (4)
__kernel __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT,1,1)))void calc_sub_hist_D0(
__global const uint4* src,
int src_step, int src_offset,
__global int* globalHist,
int dataCount,  int cols,
int inc_x, int inc_y,
int hist_step)
{
__local int subhist[(HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT << NBANKS_BIT)];
int gid = get_global_id(0);
int lid = get_local_id(0);
int gx  = get_group_id(0);
int gsize = get_global_size(0);
int lsize  = get_local_size(0);
const int shift = 8;
const int mask = HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT-1;
int offset = (lid & (NBANKS-1));
uint4 data, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4;
src += src_offset;
for(int i=0, idx=lid; i<(NBANKS >> 2); i++, idx += lsize)
{
subhist[idx] = 0;
subhist[idx+=lsize] = 0;
subhist[idx+=lsize] = 0;
subhist[idx+=lsize] = 0;
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
int y = gid/cols;
int x = gid - mul24(y, cols);
for(int idx=gid; idx<dataCount; idx+=gsize)
{
data = src[mad24(y, src_step, x)];
temp1 = ((data & mask) << NBANKS_BIT) + offset;
data >>= shift;
temp2 = ((data & mask) << NBANKS_BIT) + offset;
data >>= shift;
temp3 = ((data & mask) << NBANKS_BIT) + offset;
data >>= shift;
temp4 = ((data & mask) << NBANKS_BIT) + offset;
atomic_inc(subhist + temp1.x);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp1.y);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp1.z);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp1.w);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp2.x);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp2.y);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp2.z);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp2.w);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp3.x);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp3.y);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp3.z);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp3.w);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp4.x);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp4.y);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp4.z);
atomic_inc(subhist + temp4.w);
x += inc_x;
int off = ((x>=cols) ? -1 : 0);
x = mad24(off, cols, x);
y += inc_y - off;
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
int bin1=0, bin2=0, bin3=0, bin4=0;
for(int i=0; i<NBANKS; i+=4)
{
bin1 += subhist[(lid << NBANKS_BIT) + i];
bin2 += subhist[(lid << NBANKS_BIT) + i+1];
bin3 += subhist[(lid << NBANKS_BIT) + i+2];
bin4 += subhist[(lid << NBANKS_BIT) + i+3];
}
globalHist[mad24(gx, hist_step, lid)] = bin1+bin2+bin3+bin4;
}
__kernel void __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(1,HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT,1)))calc_sub_hist_border_D0(
__global const uchar* src,
int src_step,  int src_offset,
__global int* globalHist,
int left_col,  int cols,
int rows,   int hist_step)
{
int gidx = get_global_id(0);
int gidy = get_global_id(1);
int lidy = get_local_id(1);
int gx = get_group_id(0);
int gy = get_group_id(1);
int gn = get_num_groups(0);
int rowIndex = mad24(gy, gn, gx);
__local int subhist[HISTOGRAM256_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE];
subhist[lidy] = 0;
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
gidx = ((gidx>=left_col) ? (gidx+cols) : gidx);
if(gidy<rows)
{
int src_index = src_offset + mad24(gidy, src_step, gidx);
int p = (int)src[src_index];
atomic_inc(subhist + p);
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
globalHist[mad24(rowIndex, hist_step, lidy)] += subhist[lidy];
}
__kernel __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(256,1,1)))void merge_hist(__global int* buf,
__global int* hist,
int src_step)
{
int lx = get_local_id(0);
int gx = get_group_id(0);
int sum = 0;
for(int i = lx; i < PARTIAL_HISTOGRAM256_COUNT; i += HISTOGRAM256_WORK_GROUP_SIZE)
sum += buf[ mad24(i, src_step, gx)];
__local int data[HISTOGRAM256_WORK_GROUP_SIZE];
data[lx] = sum;
for(int stride = HISTOGRAM256_WORK_GROUP_SIZE /2; stride > 0; stride >>= 1)
{
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
if(lx < stride)
data[lx] += data[lx + stride];
}
if(lx == 0)
hist[gx] = data[0];
}
__kernel __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(256,1,1)))void calLUT(
__global uchar * dst,
__constant int * hist,
int total)
{
int lid = get_local_id(0);
__local int sumhist[HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT+1];
sumhist[lid]=hist[lid];
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
if(lid==0)
{
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;
while (!sumhist[i]) ++i;
sumhist[HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT] = sumhist[i];
for(sumhist[i++] = 0; i<HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT; i++)
{
sum+=sumhist[i];
sumhist[i]=sum;
}
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
float scale = 255.f/(total - sumhist[HISTOGRAM256_BIN_COUNT]);
dst[lid]= lid == 0 ? 0 : convert_uchar_sat(convert_float(sumhist[lid])*scale);
}
```

Comment: You have to dump the build error log. Otherwise the job of finding an error in the code is quite difficult.

Comment: The sample source does dump the log. Unfortunately, the log does not provide much information in my case. Anyways, the issue is fixed by replacing GeForce 8600 GT with Quadro 600 board. I am quite new to OpenCL but It turned out GeForce 8600GT device does not support DOUBLE_SUPPORT hardware extension which is essential for some of the OpenCL kernels used in face detect sample.