# OpenCV ocl module -

Tags: opencv, opencl, face-detection

I tried to run face detection sample in the ocl module of OpenCV. I got the following error in command line:

> unidentified identifier "int3"

Following error in VS2012

> cv::Exception at memory location xxxxx

No idea what to do!

Possible duplicate here: [ocl-facedetect sample of opencv 2.4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234996/ocl-facedetect-sample-of-opencv-2-4-6-1) . But no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the specs handy but I think the 3-component vector types didn't get added until 1.1 (or maybe 1.2). Perhaps your device only supports OpenCL 1.0. What is the device?